# What's the opposite of MATCH AGAINST?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know:

```
WHERE MATCH(title,category) AGAINST ('text')
```

But what if I want to say 'text' cannot not be anywhere in title or category?

Many thanks

Darren

Comment: I'd say just add `NOT` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "`IN BOOLEAN MODE`" with the '-' specifier

```
WHERE MATCH (title,category) AGAINST ('-text' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: Thanks @daren... for multiple words do I add a minus sign for each word? e.g. AGAINST ('-text -text2 -text3' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Comment: That should work. You might be able to apply it to a set of words using parentheses `AGAINST '-(this that)' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`, but I'm not 100% sure of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

`SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE MATCH (title,category) AGAINST ('-text' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

Answer (score 0):

Is there any problem with using `WHERE NOT MATCH(title,category) AGAINST ('text')`?